# how to hack rbash --?

Tags: bash, ctf

1. I'm solving CTF challenge, and have to escalate the privilege from user1 to user2, $HOME is read-only, so i can't change `$HOME/.bashrc`.
2. `sudo -l` shows `(user2) NOPASSOWRD: /usr/rbash --` i can't write any commands before or after --, it doesn't escalate.

I must get user2 privilege to read a file owned by it, any idea how to get through this?

while `$HOME` is user1 home, `sudo -u user2 rbash --` will cd me to my home `$HOME/jail`. in a restricted shell, and PATH is set to $HOME/jail, i have tested all possible commands that i can use to escape jail, i almost left nothing, so i can tell that `$HOME/jail` is empty directory!

Comment: Is `rbash` the real `rbash`, or is it custom/modified for the CTF? What commands are allowed?

Comment: yes i guess, it conforms to the man page description, hell of a jail!

Comment: the challenge starts with rbash shell, then you need to go escalate through 14 layers to get your target, in first layer PATH is set to $HOME/jail1 which has vim, and i can break through  it, in layer 14, once again PATH is set to $HOME/jail2, which is user2 home, and i can't use ls, or even echo *, and i tested all possible commands i can used to escalate my privilege but nothing works! so the solution around the commands rbash -- itself,

Comment: You still haven't said which commands are available at layer 14, if any.

Comment: native shell commands, and echo * lists only sl

Comment: i skimmed sl source code, i can't find  way to drop a shell through it, or read a file!

Comment: Did you try `*` by itself? Because it would execute the command if that's all there is in that folder and otherwise it gives you an error with the list of files?

Comment: echo * lists sl (steam locomotive animation)! i checked the source code, i doesn't think it's possible to command-inject sl